Past continuous how to understand the meaning
What if I say something like this "when she arrives we are playing games together". The intended meanig is that it is my plan to play games with her once we are together. Let's say  that now I want to report that sentece "he said when she arrived they were playing games together". I feel that once reported it  changes it meaning and implies that playing happened befote her arrival. My question is how to report my original sentence and keep the original meaning?

Past continuous normally means you were in the middle of playing at the time. But it can also represent repeated/regular action: if you were talking about the month or year she came, you could have something like "I was playing in a jazz band every Friday when she arrived". Without a time phrase, or with a specific arrival time, it strongly suggests you were in the middle of playing, but it's not impossible the context could suggest another meaning.

If you are asking whether the playing happened entirely after her arrival, then no. And that's mainly because of when. We get a different meaning if we say I was playing after she arrived. As @StuartF says, context is crucial.

The sentence I was vacationing when Neil Armstrong stepped onto the Moon makes no claim about my activities at any time before or after his one small step. Ok, no claim beyond those following from the laws of physics and how long it would take the speaker to enter into or to exit out of the state of being on vacation.

Please don't make dramatic edits that fundamentally change the nature of a question. Your original question here is about past tense; you edited to ask about the future. In this case, there were no answers before you edited, but if there had been, they would have stopped making sense. If you need such a radical change, please open a separate question.

This question is similar to: Past SImple vs Past Continuous. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"The intended meaning is that it is my plan to play games with her once we are together."| Then, when she arrives we are playing games is wrong. When she arrives, we're going to play games. or will play games.

You're right that "when she arrives we are playing games together" is acceptable, although it sounds a little clunky. You're more likely to hear a native speaker say "when she arrives we are going to play games together", as that sounds more like a plan that is contingent on the other person turning up.
But your second sentence doesn't seem right at all:

he said when she arrived they were playing games together

This sounds like the games were being played at the moment of arrival - ie she arrived with someone and the games were already in progress as they walked in the door. I don't think that's what you mean.
If the intention is to state what actually happened you should say:

he said that, when she arrived, they played games together.

Or, if your intention is to state what he said was going to happen, you should  say:

he said they were going to play games together when she arrived.


Thank you very much

@Dary Note, it's common for reported speech to paraphrase and perhaps change word order to whatever is most convenient in the new speaker's context. After all, it's not a direct quote!

He said when she arrived they were playing games together. Not right? Yes, it's perfectly fine. In fact, the simple past is better than the simple present there unless you're using historical present.
